# how to add MSBuild to project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have VS2010 and solution with many projects, I want to add MSBuild script to the solution(or project). How to do that? What to click to create MSBuild project script file?
The google is full of information how MSBuild is useful and what syntax it has but hard to find information how to start using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSBuild Files are just XML, in detail each *.*proj is a XML and also an valid MSBuild file.

Just unload a project in VS and choose Edit ProjectFile to dig into MSBuild